# Calling a function from a class in python

Tags: python, function, class

I'm trying to call a function from a class in python. This is my code:

```
class JCMT:
    def be(self):
       if self > 330000:
         return 0.64
       else:
         return 0.69
    def bs(self):
       if self > 330000:
         return 14
       else:
         return 20 

f = 220258

print JCMT.bs(f)
```

I'm getting an error of TypeError: unbound method bs() must be called with JCMT instance as first argument (got int instance instead)

Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 5):

There were a few problems, I addressed them with comments:

```
class JCMT:

    # Add parameter
    def bs(self, n):
       if n > 330000:
         return 14
       else:
         return 20

f = 220258

# Make a new instance
j = JCMT()

# Call now, and pass variable
print j.bs(f)
```

The `self` part in the method signature is unique.  You can read more about it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2709821/2282538).

Answer (score 5):

Add a static method decorator right above the function to denote a static function called on the class:

```
@staticmethod
```

Problem is your self parameter corresponds to an instance object which is implicitly passed during function invocation and thus an error is thrown when a class is supplied instead. You must remove the `self` argument and use an argument to denote the numerical argument.

Comment: this is also a great answer :)

Comment: This is the right way. On top, I would rename the argument from **self** to something else so as to avoid confusion with regular instance methods.

Comment: It's quite possible that this was supposed to be a regular instance method, and the OP simply forgot (or is unaware of how) to instantiate an object.

Answer (score 0):

Althout the `@staticmethod` decorator already provided in an answer solves this particular problem, if in the future you wish to use the class method and retain self, you can also use the `@classmethod` decorator to call the method directly without instantiating the class first.

```
class JCMT:
    @classmethod
    def be(self, n):
        if n > 330000:
            return 0.64
        else:
            return 0.69
    @classmethod
    def bs(self, n):
        if n > 330000:
            return 14
        else:
            return 20 

f = 220258

print JCMT.bs(f)
20
```